# Block master branch being pushed if file modified

Tags: git, hook, push

As we have multiple servers in production I am trying to simplify the code deployment procedure.

For deployment automation I referred the following link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps which was very helpful.

But the problem is that in our case we have to address our customers problems immediately and hence end up modifying the code on production servers.
Hence, we cannot afford to lose the changes due to the git push.

I added a check in the post-receive hook to check if there is modification  to any file as follows.

```
MODIFICATIONS="git --work-tree=/code/path --git-dir=/home/git/repo_path status | grep modified:"

if [ -z "$MODIFICATIONS" ];then
        git --work-tree=/code/path --git-dir=/home/git/repo_path checkout -f
   else
        echo "Modified present !!!"
fi
```

This helps in retaining the changes to the files. But every `git push prod1 master` updates the repository.

I tried pre-receive & update hooks but they don't work (I think because I am constantly pushing the same branch `master`).

Please suggest how I can avoid changes from even being pushed to the remote git repository to `master` branch.
So when I say `git push prod1 master` it should give me an error.

Comment: "we have to address our customers problems immediately and hence end up modifying the code on production servers" This doesn't follow. There are lots of ways you can react to your customers' needs quickly that don't involve modifying code directly in production. Your _real_ solution will be to adjust your workflow accordingly.

Comment: @Chris "If anything can happen, will happen." Not an excuse to adjust your workflow, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't lecture about the evils associated with "modifying the code on production servers" - It is terrible practice, but you're in a certain situation and it is what it is.

However, you can simply ask the developers that are modifying the code on the production servers to check in their code regularly, even if only to the local git repository on the server itself using a command such as `git commit -a -m "emergency change for customer xyz"`

This way, even though the changes are not being merged back into the actual development repository, they are being tracked on the machine where they were made.

This will indeed block incoming changes when somebody does `git push prod1 master`, since the master branch will have diverged from the master branch on the development repository and there will be no way to fast-forward a push.

If you follow this advice, the command `git push prod1 master` should end up producing an error, just as you've asked for.